# How to install the module pysqlite2

Tags: python, module, installation, package

I want to install the `PySqlite2` module in my python library. I opened command prompt and went to the download directory. This contains the `Pysqlite-2.6.3` package extracted. I entered python setup.py install. It starts copying all the files untill it gives: `Errror: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.` I can't seem to figure to out. My systems runs a 32bit version of windows 7.

Comment: Google is one of the best tools. Try searching the error https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Errror%3A+Unable+to+find+vcvarsall.bat&oq=Errror%3A+Unable+to+find+vcvarsall.bat&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.246j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

While running `setup.py` for package installations `Python 2.7` searches for an installed Visual Studio 2008. You can trick Python to use a newer Visual Studio by setting the correct path in `VS90COMNTOOLS` environment variable before calling `setup.py`.

[Find more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Thanks, I installed Windows visual 2008 and it does not seem to happen. But now I get another error: Raise Valueerror<str<list<result.leys<>>>>    ValueError: [u'path']

Comment: You can try this link http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279